# Subtype polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Building a hierarchy of GUI widget classes is pretty much a standard exercise in object-oriented programming. You have some sort of abstract `Widget` class, with an abstract subclass for widgets that can contain other widgets, and then you have a profusion of further abstract classes for widgets that support textual display, widgets that support being the input focus, widgets that have a boolean state, right down to actual concrete classes such as buttons, sliders, scrollbars, check boxes, etc.

My question is: What is the best way to do this in Haskell?

There are a number of things that make building a Haskell GUI difficult, but are *not* part of my question. Doing interactive I/O is mildly tricky in Haskell. Implementing a GUI almost always means writing a wrapper to an extremely low-level C or C++ library. And people writing such wrappers tend to copy the existing API verbatim (presumably so anybody who knows the wrapped library will feel at home). These problems do not interest me at the moment. I'm interested purely in how best to model subtype polymorphism in Haskell.

What kind of properties would we want from our hypothetical GUI library? Well, we want it to be possible to add new widget types at any time. (In other words, a closed set of possible widgets is no good.) We want to minimise code duplication. (There are *a lot* of widget types!) Ideally we want to be able to stipulate one specific widget type when necessary, but also to be able to handle collections of *any* widget type if needed.

All of the above is of course trivial in any self-respecting OO language. But what is the best way to do this in Haskell? I can think of several approaches, but I'm not sure which one would be "best".

Comment: "What kind of properties would we want from our hypothetical GUI library?" Not being OO, for starters.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Which is really difficult. Especially GUI design is one of the few areas where OO really shines. I would really like to see some GUI library designed in a different paradigm, but almost all I know cling to some way of doing things in an object-y way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what OOP, such as subtype polymorphism, can be done in Haskell you can look at [OOHaskell](https://web.archive.org/web/20100117105118/http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/OOHaskell/).  This reproduces the semantics of a variety of powerful OOP type systems, keeping most type inference.  The actual data encoding was not being optimized, but I suspect type families might allow better presentations.

Modelling the interface hierarchy (e.g. Widget) can be done with type classes.  Adding new instances is possible and so the set of concrete widgets is open.  If you want a specific list of possible widgets then GADTs can be a succinct solution.

The special operation with subclasses is upcasting and downcasting.

This is first needed to have a collection of Widgets, and usual result is to use existential types.  There are other interesting solutions if you read all the bits of the [HList library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.2.3).  The upcasting is fairly easy and the compiler can be certain that all casts are valid at compilation time.  The downcasting is inherently dynamic and requires some run-time type information support, usually Data.Typeable.  Given something like Typeable the downcasting is just another type class, with the result wrapped in Maybe to indicate failure.

There is boilerplate associated with most of this, but QuasiQuoting and Templating can reduce this.  The type inference can still largely work.

I have not explored the new Constraint kinds and types, but they may augment the existential solution to upcasting and downcasting.

Answer (score 34):

Having actual widget objects is something that's very object-oriented. A commonly used technique in the functional world is to instead use Functional Reactive Programming (FRP). I'll briefly outline what a widget library in pure Haskell would look like when using FRP.

---

**tl/dr:** You don't handle "Widget objects", you handle collections of "event streams" instead, and don't care from which widgets or where those streams come from.

---

In FRP, there's the basic notion of an `Event a`, which can be seen as an infinite list `[(Time, a)]`. So, if you want to model a counter that counts up, you'd write it as `[(00:01, 1), (00:02, 4), (00.03, 7), ...]`, which associates a specific counter value with a given time. If you want to model a button that is being pressed, you produce a `[(00:01, ButtonPressed), (00:02, ButtonReleased), ...]`

There's also commonly something called a `Signal a`, which is like an `Event a`, except that the modeled value is continuous. You don't have a discrete set of values at specific times, but you can ask the `Signal` for its value at, say, `00:02:231` and it will give you the value `4.754` or something. Think of a signal as an analogue signal like the one on a heart charge meter (electrocardiographic device/Holter monitor) at a hospital: it's a continuous line that jumps up and down but never makes a "gap". A window does always have a title, for example (but perhaps it's the empty string), so you can always ask it for its value.

---

In a GUI library, on a low level, there'd be a `mouseMovement :: Event (Int, Int)` and `mouseAction :: Event (MouseButton, MouseAction)` or something. The `mouseMovement` is the actual USB/PS2 mouse output, so you only get position differences as events (e.g. when the user moves the mouse up, you'd get the event `(12:35:235, (0, -5))`. You'd then be able to "integrate" or rather "accumulate" the movement events to get a `mousePosition :: Signal (Int, Int)` that gave you absolute mouse coordinates. `mousePosition` could also take into consideration absolute pointing devices such as touch screens, or OS events that reposition the mouse cursor, etc.

Similarly for a keyboard, there'd be a `keyboardAction :: Event (Key, Action)`, and one could also "integrate" that event stream into a `keyboardState :: Signal (Key -> KeyState)` that lets you read a key's state at any point in time.

---

Things get more complicated when you want to draw stuff onto the screen and interact with widgets.

To create just a single window, one would have a "magic function" called:

```
window :: Event DrawCommand -> Signal WindowIcon -> Signal WindowTitle -> ...
       -> FRP (Event (Int, Int) {- mouse events -},
               Event (Key, Action) {- key events -},
               ...)
```

The function would be magical because it would have to call the OS-specific functions and create a window (unless the OS itself is FRP, but I doubt that). That is also why it is in the `FRP` monad, because it would call `createWindow` and `setTitle` and `registerKeyCallback` etc in the `IO` monad behind the scenes.

One could of course group all of those values into data structures so that there would be:

```
window :: WindowProperties -> ReactiveWidget
       -> FRP (ReactiveWindow, ReactiveWidget)
```

The `WindowProperties` are signals and events that determine the look and behavior of the window (e.g. if there should be close buttons, what the title should be, etc.).

The `ReactiveWidget` represents S&Es that are keyboard and mouse events, in case you want to emulate mouse clicks from within your application, and an `Event DrawCommand` that represents a stream of things you want to draw on the window. This data structure is common to all widgets.

The `ReactiveWindow` represents events like the window being minimized etc, and the output `ReactiveWidget` represents mouse and keyboard events coming from the outside/the user.

Then one would create an actual widget, let's say a push button. It would have the signature:

```
button :: ButtonProperties -> ReactiveWidget -> (ReactiveButton, ReactiveWidget)
```

The `ButtonProperties` would determine the color/text/etc of the button, and the `ReactiveButton` would contain e.g. an `Event ButtonAction` and `Signal ButtonState` to read the button's state.

Note that the `button` function is a pure function, since it only depends on pure FRP values like events and signals.

If one wants to group widgets (e.g. stack them horizontally), one would have to create e.g. a:

```
horizontalLayout :: HLayoutProperties -> ReactiveWidget
                 -> (ReactiveLayout, ReactiveWidget)
```

The `HLayoutProperties` would contain information about border sizes and the `ReactiveWidget`s for the contained widgets. The `ReactiveLayout` would then contain a `[ReactiveWidget]` with one element for each child widget.

What the layout would do is that it would have an internal `Signal [Int]` that determined the height of each widget in the layout. It would then receive all of the events from the input `ReactiveWidget`, then based upon the partition layout select an output `ReactiveWidget` to send the event to, meanwhile also transforming the origin of e.g. mouse events by the partition offset.

---

To demonstrate how this API would work, consider this program:

```
main = runFRP $ do rec -- Recursive do, lets us use winInp lazily before it is defined

  -- Create window:
  (win, winOut) <- window winProps winInp

      -- Create some arbitrary layout with our 2 widgets:
  let (lay, layOut) = layout (def { widgets = [butOut, labOut] }) layInp
      -- Create a button:
      (but, butOut) = button butProps butInp
      -- Create a label:
      (lab, labOut) = label labProps labInp
      -- Connect the layout input to the window output
      layInp = winOut
      -- Connect the layout output to the window input
      winInp = layOut
      -- Get the spliced input from the layout
      [butInp, layInp] = layoutWidgets lay
      -- "pure" is of course from Applicative Functors and indicates a constant Signal
      winProps = def { title = pure "Hello, World!", size = pure (800, 600) }
      butProps = def { title = pure "Click me!" }
      labProps = def { text = reactiveIf
                              (buttonPressed but)
                              (pure "Button pressed") (pure "Button not pressed") }
  return ()
```

(`def` is from `Data.Default` in `data-default`)

This creates an event graph, like so:

```
     Input events ->            Input events ->
win ---------------------- lay ---------------------- but \
     <- Draw commands etc.  \   <- Draw commands etc.      | | Button press ev.
                             \  Input events ->            | V
                              \---------------------- lab /
                                <- Draw commands etc.
```

Note that there doesn't have to be any "widget objects" anywhere. A layout is simply a function that transforms input and output events according to a partitioning system, so you could use the event streams you gain access to for widgets, or you could let another sub-system generate the streams entirely. The same goes for buttons and labels: they are simply functions that convert click events into draw commands, or similar things. It's a representation of complete decoupling, and very flexible in its nature.

Comment: Is `rec` actually a thing in Haskell?

Comment: @dbaupp: GHC extension: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#recursive-do-notation

Comment: Maybe I got the syntax wrong, I obviously didn't compile the code, so take it with a grain of salt!

Comment: That's an interesting description of how you might connect a Haskell program to an existing set of widgets. But it doesn't address how you might _implement_ them. Imagine, for example, that you only have the ability to write pixels and read mouse events. How would you write a complete GUI stack?

Comment: Well, most basic drawing libraries at least let you draw rectangles, ellipses and gradients etc. Just drawing pixels would be quite limiting. But the actual implementation of a button might look like: `button _ (ReactiveWidget { mouseClick = mc, mouseDown = md }) = (ReactiveButton { buttonPressed = md }, ReactiveWidget { drawCommands = reactiveIf md (FRect 0 0 25 25 White) (FRect 0 0 25 25 Black), mouseClick = mc })`. I obviously don't have much space in this comment, but that button (for simplicity with size 25x25) would react to clicks, and be black when pressed and white when not pressed.

Comment: For real-world FRP examples, see [`reactive-banana`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) and an example package demonstrating an adapter to wxWidgets in [`reactive-banana-wx`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-wx), or [`grapefruit-ui`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grapefruit-ui) with an adapter for GTK in [`grapefruit-ui-gtk`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grapefruit-ui-gtk). Those libraries are obviously adapters, so they still use a set of "ordinary", non-reactive widgets in the different libraries they are based on.

Answer (score 10):

The [wxHaskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell) GUI library makes excellent use of **phantom types** to model a widget hierarchy.

The idea is the following: all widgets share the same implementation, namely they are foreign pointers to C++ objects. However, this doesn't mean that all widgets need to have the same type. Instead, we can build a hierarchy like this:

```
type Object a = ForeignPtr a

data CWindow a
data CControl a
data CButton a

type Window  a = Object  (CWindow a)
type Control a = Window  (CControl a)
type Button  a = Control (CButton a)
```

This way, a value of the type `Control A` also matches the type `Window b`, so you can use controls as windows, but not the other way round. As you can see, subtyping is implemented via a nested type parameter.

For more on this technique, see section 5 in [Dan Leijen's paper on wxHaskell](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/papers/wxhaskell.pdf).

---

Note that this technique appears to be limited to the case where the actual representation of widgets is uniform, i.e. always the same. However, I am confident that with some thought, it can be extended to the case where widgets have different representations.

In particular, the observation is that object-orientation can be modeled by including the methods in the data type, like this

```
data CWindow a = CWindow
    { close   :: IO ()
    , ...
    }
data CButton a = CButton
    { onClick :: (Mouse -> IO ()) -> IO ()
    , ...
    }
```

Subtyping may save some boilerplate here, but it's not required.

Comment: Can you expand on why subtyping is not required here? How would you handle the things which are handled by subtyping in the original library?