# How to return type of certain typeclass in a function

Tags: haskell

I would like to remove the repetitive code in the following code, by providing a function that returns a value of instance of certain typeclass(ClassA in this example):

```hs
class ClassA a where
  f :: a -> Int
data A1 = A1 Int Int
instance ClassA A1 where
  f (A1 v1 v2) = v1 + v2
data A2 = A2 Int Int
instance ClassA A2 where
  f (A2 v1 v2) = v1 * v2

g1 :: ClassA a => a -> Int
g1 iA = f iA + 1
g2 :: ClassA a => a -> Int
g2 iA = f iA + 2

class ClassB b where
  newB :: Int -> b
  h1 :: b -> Int
  h2 :: b -> Int

data B1 = B1 A1
fromB1toA1 :: B1 -> A1
fromB1toA1 (B1 a) = a
instance ClassB B1 where
  newB v = B1 (A1 v v)
  h1 b = let a = fromB1toA1 b in g1 a -- repeative code!!
  h2 b = let a = fromB1toA1 b in g2 a -- repeative code!!

data B2 = B2 A2
fromB2toA2 :: B2 -> A2
fromB2toA2 (B2 a) = a
instance ClassB B2 where
  newB v = B2 (A2 v v)
  h1 b = let a = fromB2toA2 b in g2 a -- repeative code!!
  h2 b = let a = fromB2toA2 b in g2 a -- repeative code!!

main = do
  let a1 = A1 2 4
  let a2 = A2 2 4
  print (f a1, g1 a1, g2 a1)
  print (f a2, g1 a2, g2 a1)

  let b1 = B1 (A1 5 5)
  let b2 = B2 (A2 6 6)
  print (h1 b1, h2 b1)
  print (h1 b2, h2 b2)

  print "bye"
```

I was trying to do things like this, but it didn't compile for me:

```hs
class ClassB b where
  newB :: Int -> b
  toClassA :: (ClassA a) => b -> a
  h1 :: b -> Int
  h1 b = let a = toClassA b in g1 a -- doesn't compile
  h2 :: b -> Int
  h2 b = let a = toClassA b in g2 a -- doesn't cimpile

data B1 = B1 A1
instance ClassB B1 where
  newB v = B1 (A1 v v)
  toClassA (B1 a) = a -- doesn't compile

data B2 = B2 A2
instance ClassB B2 where
  newB v = B2 (A2 v v)
  toClassA (B2 a) = a  -- doesn't compile
```

Comment: You can _not_ "choose to return some particular type". A function must always return the type declared in its signature, and there are no subtypes. You're abusing type classes here, they're not a replacement for OO classes.

Comment: What is it that you're working on? Have you got some context for this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I couldn't find a example that with sufficient context while being short enough. But I did find that the problem I wanted to describe can be categorized as "subtyping" problem in Polymorphism ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism#Subtyping ) . And according to: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Polymorphism , "There are some kinds of polymorphism that Haskell doesn't support, or at least not natively, e.g. inclusion polymorphism and subtyping, common in OO languages, where values of one type can act as values of another type. "

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a example that with sufficient context while being short enough.

But I did find that the problem I wanted to describe can be categorized as "subtyping" problem in Polymorphism ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism#Subtyping ).

And according to: haskell.org/haskellwiki/Polymorphism, "There are some kinds of polymorphism that Haskell doesn't support, or at least not natively, e.g. inclusion polymorphism and subtyping, common in OO languages, where values of one type can act as values of another type. "

Duplication of : [Subtype polymorphism in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002979/subtype-polymorphism-in-haskell)